# Dojo toolkit Do not load the libraries

Tags: javascript, dojo

I started on a new project where it is used the javascript Dojo Toolkit library.

I am following [the tutorial of the Dojo Toolkit's own website](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/hello_dojo/index.html) to learn how to use the tool. But I'm in trouble in the second example:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tutorial: Hello Dojo!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="greeting">Hello</h1>
    <!-- load Dojo -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"
            data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>

    <script>
        require([
            'dojo/dom',
            'dojo/dom-construct'
        ], function (dom, domConstruct) {
            var greetingNode = dom.byId('greeting');
            domConstruct.place('<em> Dojo!</em>', greetingNode);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is very simple. On the line where appears the word "Hello" should be added -at Dojo- with the word "Dojo", forming the phrase "Hello Dojo". But only appears the word "Helo". Ie the Dojo libraries are not being carregdas!

Any suggestion?

Comment: The code you have posted works fine for me...

Comment: does your web app have access to the internet ?. Bcos dojo.js is loaded from `ajax.googleapis.com`. Can you check in the debug window whether `dojo.js` is being loaded?

Comment: Indeed, what @frank says. You either have no network connection, or something is blocking it (JavaScript disabled, certain extensions, ...) or, what I think is more likely, is that you're running this example by double clicking on the HTML page itself, running over the `file://` protocol. This is not a good practice and obviously it won't be able to find the Dojo library over a protocol-relative URL if you're using `file://`. The example itself works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/x79fwcd7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the link:

FROM:
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"

TO:
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.2/dojo/dojo.js"

It worked!